# How to remove corner indices of 2D array?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, multidimensional-array, three.js, 2d

Working on forward ray tracing algorithm using Three.js. Just created this example by using a 2D array. Notice that the Spotlight is not involved here except the parsing of its location.

So in order to shoot lines I declared:

```
startPoint = position of SpotLight
endPoint   = hard code for the first value
```

[image]

Then I create a nested for loop (17x17) and I create a ray every iteration with the usual way as shown below:

```
forward_RT(){

    //Declare the start and end points of the first ray (startPoint never changes )
    var f_ray_startPoint = new THREE.Vector3(spotLight.position.x, spotLight.position.y, spotLight.position.z);
    var f_ray_endPoint = new THREE.Vector3(-490, 0, 495); //Hard Coding for 1st position of ray endPoint

    //Declare material of rays
    var ray_material_red = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, opacity: 10} );
    var ray_material_yellow = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );
    var ray_material_green = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );

    //Declare ray geometry
    var ray_geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    ray_geometry.vertices.push( f_ray_startPoint );
    ray_geometry.vertices.push( f_ray_endPoint );

    //Declare values for 2d array grid
    var rows = 17;
    var cols = 17;
    var rayOffset = 60; //Offset of ray every X iteration

    for(var x=0; x<rows; x++){
        for(var z=0; z<cols; z++){
            //Declare a ray
            var f_ray = new THREE.Line(ray_geometry.clone(), ray_material_red);
            f_ray.geometry.vertices[1].x = f_ray_endPoint.x;

            scene_Main.add(f_ray); //Add ray into the scene
            f_ray_endPoint.x += rayOffset; //Add offset every new ray

            if(f_ray_endPoint.x >= 490){
                f_ray_endPoint.x -= (cols * rayOffset);
            }
        }
        f_ray_endPoint.z -= rayOffset;
    }
}
```

For the graphics folks, I have noticed that opacity doesn't work on the material of the [Three.Line](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Line).

**Is There a way to add transparency on the line?**

---

***Main Question***

How to block the iteration so that the corners of the SpotLight will not be drawn? In other words, I want access only to rays that are inside the white circle (SpotLights).

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to maintain a discreet grid of X, Y rays and discard those outside the circle, you could use the [built-in method `Vector2.distanceTo()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Vector2.distanceTo). Simply keep your loop as it is, but do a distance calculation to the center of the circle, if the distance is larger than the radius, skip to the next loop:

```js
// Find the center of your circle
var center = new THREE.Vector2(centerX, centerZ);
// Assign radius of your circle
var radius = 17 / 2;
// Temp vector to calculate distance per iteration
var rayEnd = new THREE.Vector2();
// Result of distance
var distance = 0;

for (var x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
    for (var z = 0; z < cols; z++) {
        // Set this ray's end position
        rayEnd.set(x, z);
        // Calculate distance to center
        distance = rayEnd.distanceTo(center);

        // Skip loop if distance to center is bigger than radius
        if (distance > radius) {
            continue;
        } else {
            // Draw ray to x, z
        }
    }
}
```

A few recommendations:

1. I would use a single [LineSegments](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/objects/LineSegments) object, instead of multiple `Line` objects for faster rendering (Three.js is faster at rendering one object with many vertices than many objects with few vertices).
2. You could generate the geometry around the origin (from -8 to 8), and calculate the distance to (0, 0), and *then* displace it by 60 units with `position.x = 60`, for simplicity.

Comment: A great answer. Thank you very much.. Works like a charm :D [Image example](https://ibb.co/XD4NtrJ)

Comment: any ideas how to draw them in the scene - grow the line pixel by pixel during X time? Please if you know any useful links relevant with lines let me know.

Comment: Not sure about that, but you could probably ask the people at https://discourse.threejs.org/